# Running get_posts within get_posts to get children of children

Tags: custom-post-types, get-posts, children

I have a hierarchal custom post type called “**courses**”.

When you arrive on a course post there’s a check to see if the post has children. If the courses post **has** children it runs **get_posts** to display a list of those children.

Here’s where I’m struggling; part of the detail of a child list item is to display the number of children that child post has. So what I’ve tried to do is run a get_posts *within* a get_posts, but this is not working as expected.

To put things in context, and perhaps explain things better, here’s some of the hierarchy:

- Adobe > Acrobat > Introductory Course
- Adobe > FrameMaker > Advanced Course
- Adobe > FrameMaker > Introductory Course

So when a visitor clicks on “**Adobe**” they get a list of the children, two items:

- Acrobat; &
- Framemaker.

Underneath these titles should be detail of how many sub-courses are available, so Acrobat should say; “*1 course available*” and Framemaker should say “*2 courses available*”.

This doesn't work. The sub `get_posts` returns nothing. My specific question is; how do I find out how many children a child has when inside a `get_posts` loop. Or should I try a different approach?

My current (simplified) code...

```
$postid = get_the_ID();
$kids = array(
    'post_type' => 'courses',
    'post_parent' => $postid
);
$children = get_posts( $kids );
if ( $children ) {
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach( $children as $child ) {
        $childid = $child->ID;
        $coursetitle = get_the_title( $childid );
        $grandkids = get_posts( array(
            'post_type' => 'courses',
            'post_parent' => $childid
        ) );
        $grandchildren = count($grandkids);
        echo '<li>';
        echo $coursetitle;
        echo $grandchildren . 'courses available';
        echo '</li>';
    }
}
```

Any help from you wise ones would be much appreciated.

Comment: You can use [`get_terms`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/) to retrieve an array of children of a specific term (in your case "Adobe"). Then take the length of that array.

Comment: you don't set `post_type`, so it defaults to `post`.

Comment: Hey @cjbj thank you for the response. Can you help me understand "_take the length of that array_". How would I use, in my case, get_terms to work out how many children the post **Framemaker** has?

Comment: Hey @Milo, sorry, over simplification on my part, _post_type_ is in there. The count returns "**1**" regardless of the number of children.

Comment: Are everything under `Adobe` posts, or are they terms

Comment: Hi @PieterGoosen they are child and grandchild posts. It's a custom post type with hierarchy.

Comment: That would be `length(get_terms('your_taxonomy',array('child_of' => 'Framemaker_ID')));` You will have to fill in the name of your taxonomy and the ID of the term. Note that from what I understand the deepest level in the hierarchy is still a taxonomy and not a post. So I gather that it is not two posts in the taxonomy Framemaker you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should work, it might be that your posts per page option in back end is set to `1`. It would be beneficial to explicitely set `posts_per_page` in your query args.  You can also make the code faster if you only need to know the amount of grandchild posts, you can just return the post ids's.

Here is an example: (*Copied and modified from your code*)

```
$postid = get_the_ID();
$kids = array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_type'      => 'courses',
    'post_parent'    => $postid
);
$children = get_posts( $kids );
if ( $children ) {
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach( $children as $child ) {
        $childid     = $child->ID;
        $coursetitle = get_the_title( $childid );
        $grandkids   = get_posts( array(
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'fields'         => 'ids', // Only get post id's, much faster
            'post_type'      => 'courses',
            'post_parent'    => $childid
        ) );
        $grandchildren = count( $grandkids );
        echo '<li>';
        echo $coursetitle;
        echo $grandchildren . 'courses available';
        echo '</li>';
    }
}
```

If that does not work, you most probably have something intefering with your query, maybe a bad `pre_get_posts` action somewhere. To test this out, add `remove_all_actions( 'pre_get_posts' );` before your query.

You can also have a look at [`get_pages()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_pages) to run your queries which will not be altered by the normal `WP_Query` filters and actions